# Trying to iterate and join Pandas DFs: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to pull the historical data for ~200 securities in a given index. I import the list of securities from a csv file then iterate over them to pull their respective data from the quandl api. That dataframe for each security has 12 columns, so I create a new column with the name of the security and the Adjusted Close value, so I can later identify the series.

I'm receiving an error when I try to join all the new columns into an empty dataframe. I receive an attribute error:

```
'''
Print output data
'''
grab_constituent_data()
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Below is the code I have used to arrive here thus far.

```
'''
Import the modules necessary for analysis
'''

import quandl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

'''
Set file pathes and API keys
'''

ticker_path = ''
auth_key = ''

'''
Pull a list of tickers in the IGM ETF
'''

def ticker_list():
    df = pd.read_csv('{}IGM Tickers.csv'.format(ticker_path))
    # print(df['Ticker'])
    return df['Ticker']

'''
Pull the historical prices for the securities within Ticker List
'''

def grab_constituent_data():
    tickers = ticker_list()
    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for abbv in tickers:
        query = 'EOD/{}'.format(str(abbv))
        df = quandl.get(query, authtoken=auth_key)
        print('Competed the query for {}'.format(query))

        df['{} Adj_Close'.format(str(abbv))] = df['Adj_Close'].copy()
        df = df['{} Adj_Close'.format(str(abbv))]
        print('Completed the column adjustment for {}'.format(str(abbv)))

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df)

    print(main_df.head())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that in your line

```
df = df['{} Adj_Close'.format(str(abbv))]
```

you're getting a Serie and not a Dataframe. If you want to convert your serie to a dataframe, you can use the function to_frame() like:

```
df = df['{} Adj_Close'.format(str(abbv))].to_frame()
```

I didn't check if your code might be more simple, but this should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To change a series into pandas dataframe you can use the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

After running above code, the series will become dataframe, then you can proceed with join tasks you have mentioned earlier